# How to compile HTML

Tags: html, compilation

Is it possible to compile HTML? It wouldn't be that hard since all tags could easily be replaced with bytes which would speed up the lexical analyzer since it wouldn't have to query as much from the stream. It would also make the webpage a lot smaller and easier to send to the client.

If it is not possible are there specific reasons as to why not?

Comment: Not entirely what you asked, but there are smaller versions of HTML like HAML.

Comment: HTML is a markup language with an interpreter (though its not Turing complete). The standard makes the markup human readable with tags. There's no way to compile it down to byte code or native code. Its not unlike asking how you make make an ELF or PE binary out of HTML or XML or asking why it does not run as a marked up executable.

Comment: @jww I'm not saying you compile it down to something like an ELF or MACH-O file I'm saying you can very easily map tags to bytes (probably 2 to handle the larger number of tags that could be possible) similar how to ASM translates directly into byte streams, which would make the file smaller (most of the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to compile HTML ? HTML response, when sent from server to client is already in the form of bitstrings. Moreover, Even if you are applying any custom transformation, How'll you assure that at the client-side, decoding is performed to obtain original response.

However, If you concern is response-compression to use network bandwidth effectively, then there are other means to do the same :-

1. Minify minified CSS, JS files. You can even aggregate all
   application-level CSS, JS files into one big file and send it in one
   go, to avoid unnecessary network calls.
2. Set content-encoding as gzip(But make sure to check "Accept" header
   in the request)
3. Use cache for static files.

For more info., refer to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html.
Hoping it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need compile your html templates??

It is possible compile a html template in string for later used in other sites. absolutely you can do this with javascript frameworks like angularjs..

this is a example

http://blog.timsommer.be/using-compile-to-compile-html-strings-in-angular/